Name TV show with agent mom gay son and daughter
There was this TV show that I have watched that came out some time after 2010 (I would guess 2013 or 2014) that had a mother who was like a secret agent or something.
She was pretty badass. She also had two kids (that I know of.) One a son who was gay and looked like he was 18 or 19 the other a daughter who was like 16. 
I only saw one episode and in that episode the gay sons partner got shot and died. 
The three also appeared to be on the run from a group of men. I believe the show is American or Canadian.

Welcome to the community. That's not a lot to go on, plot-wise. Any other plot details? I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

Thanks @John. I only saw one episode so I don't know much about the series plot. The mother, daughter and son appeared to be trying to allude someone by car at the beginning of the episode. They arrived at there house and hid in some secrete room. The men chasing them broke into there home. At some point in there the son's boyfriend comes over and gets killed. I know the family then alludes the men and eventually kills all the men that were chasing them. Other then that I don't know or remember much about the series of the plot.

Chosen (season 3)

We meet hunter Josie Acosta (Rose McGowan) and her teenagers Alex (Alexander Le Bas) and Megan (Sammi Hanratty)

3x1



3x3




Thank you very much. This is the show I was looking for.

@Zdog123 If this is the answer that you were looking for, kindly accept the answer so that it is resolved.  Thank you :)
